# Using if(isset($_POST['submit'])) to display message but it is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I tried to write simple Form validation with PHP. When click submit button if the name is empty then the website will ask the user to fill in. But when i click the submit button nothing appear on the screen. Can you help me how to fix this problem? Thank you. Here is my code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["Ename"])){

    }else{
        echo"Please enter your name";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
Tutor name: <input type="text" name="Ename" value="">
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Submit your record" name="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you tried to `var_dump` everything available in `$_POST` array on form submit? And where is `<form>` element for submission?

Comment: `type="button"` won't submit the form, that's `type="submit"`

Comment: Try using if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) as isset() tells you the variable has been defined or not, not whether it has been populated. Further keep action="" as you are going to remain on same page

Answer (score 0):

write `<input>` tag in `<form>` tag and set input `type="submit"`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (!empty($_POST["Ename"])) {

    } else {
        echo "Please enter your name";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        Tutor name: <input type="text" name="Ename" value="">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit your record" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to wrap your form inputs and submit button in a `<form>` tag, like this:

```
<html>
    <form method="post">
        Tutor name: <input type="text" name="Ename" value="">
        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Submit your record" name="submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest, you missing `method` attribute for `<form>` here.

Comment: Hi i just update my code above. I have form and method post but I dont know why it dont display the message.

Comment: Might be because it doesn't it doesn't really add any value. That's a $_GET form that will never submit, kind of "useless"

Comment: Downvotes without comment aren't very useful, true but they state that someone found this answer not useful - which it wasn't and still is. Did you test that code? Does your form submit? (It doesn't!)